# Raytracing multiple objects closest distance computation

Tags: c++, math, graphics, raytracing

I am writing a raytracer in c++ and I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly draw multiple objects (here spheres for now). I cast rays on each pixels of the set screen resolution and iterate on each objects of my scene for each ray. Here is the code:

```cpp
for (unsigned int y = 0; y < m_resY; y++) {
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < m_resX; x++) {
        if (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0) {
            m_buffer[y * m_resX + x].color = Color(-1, -1, -1);
            continue;
        }
        double u = (double(x) * 2 / (m_resX - 1)) - 1;
        double v = (double(y) * 2 / (m_resY - 1)) - 1;
        RayTracer::Ray r = m_camera.ray(u, v);
        double closestDist = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
        for (auto &obj : m_objects) {
            if (obj->hits(r)) {
                if (std::abs(r.getHit().dist) < std::abs(closestDist)) {
                    closestDist = r.getHit().dist;
                    r.setClosestObj(obj.get());
                    r.getClosestHit() = r.getHit();
                }
            } else if (m_buffer[y * m_resX + x].computed == false) {
                m_buffer[y * m_resX + x].color = Color(50, 50, 50);
            }
        }
        if (r.getClosestObj() != nullptr) {
            m_light->computeLight(r, *r.getClosestObj(), m_objects);
            m_buffer[y * m_resX + x].color = r.m_finalColor;
            m_buffer[y * m_resX + x].computed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the hits method:

```cpp
bool Sphere::hits(Ray &ray) const
{
    Math::Vector3<double> ocp = ray.m_origin - m_center;
    Math::Vector3<double> oc = Math::Vector3<double>(ocp.x, ocp.y, ocp.z);

    double a = ray.m_direction.dot(ray.m_direction);
    double b = 2.0f * oc.dot(ray.m_direction);
    double c = oc.dot(oc) - m_radius * m_radius;
    double discriminant = b * b - 4.0f * a * c;

    if (discriminant < 0)
        return false;
    ray.getHit().dist = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0f * a);
    ray.getHit().hitPosition = ray.m_origin + ray.m_direction * ray.getHit().dist;
    ray.getHit().normal = ray.getHit().hitPosition - m_center;
    return true;
}
```

and the output:

[image]

I have tried to normalize the ray direction vector, use the discriminant as comparative, compare [-b - sqrt ...] to [-b + sqrt ...] but still same issue

Comment: One thing you code is missing, is to check if the hit is in front of or behind the camera.
Also yes, for your code to work, you need to make sure that m_direction has norm 1, how did you ensure that ?

Comment: the hit can't be behind the camera as the ray is emited from it (its z direction is always -1), and yes, the ray m_direction is normalized when it is created

Comment: Hello! When asking questions on stackoverflow it is strongly recommended, if you include code in your question, to make that code a [mre]. Here it appears that there is an issue with displaying the red ball in addition to the blue ball. A very relevant information would be: is the red ball supposed to be behind or in front of the blue ball? We don't know, because the positions of these two balls are not included in the code you've included in the question.

Comment: From your code, I understand that ray.getHit().dist can be negative or positive, in which case the hit can be either in front or behind the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that worked, somehow inverting the z (depth position) of the objects, the distance was correctly computed.

My camera was in 0 0 0 and shooting rays with z = 1, and the objects were in -1, now the objects are in 1 and it produces the correct render.